# Генерация ШИМ без analogWrite()

Tags: c, arduino

Я пишу кастомное ядро для Arduino Mega 2560 и мне нужно генерировать ШИМ, кодом такого вида:

```
bitSet(TCCR0A, COM0A1);
        OCR0A = duty;
```

Какие значения мне нужно подставить, чтобы ШИМ был не только на 13 пине (таймера...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот работающий код:

```
 switch (pin) {
    case 2:
      bitSet(TCCR3A, COM3B1);
      OCR3B = duty; // set pwm duty
      return;
    case 3:
      bitSet(TCCR3A, COM3C1);
      OCR3C = duty; // set pwm duty
      return;
    case 4:
      bitSet(TCCR0A, COM0B1);
      OCR0B = duty; // set pwm duty
      return;
    case 5:
      bitSet(TCCR3A, COM3A1);
      OCR3A = duty; // set pwm duty
      return;
    case 6:
      bitSet(TCCR4A, COM4A1);
      OCR4A = duty; // set pwm duty
      return;
    case 7:
      bitSet(TCCR4A, COM4B1);
      OCR4B = duty; // set pwm duty
      return;
    case 8:
      bitSet(TCCR4A, COM4C1);
      OCR4C = duty; // set pwm duty
      return;
    case 9:
      bitSet(TCCR2A, COM2B1);
      OCR2B = duty; // set pwm duty
      return;
    case 10:
      bitSet(TCCR2A, COM2A1);
      OCR2A = duty;
      return;
    case 11:
      bitSet(TCCR1A, COM1A1);
      OCR1A = duty;
      return;
    case 12:
      bitSet(TCCR1A, COM1B1);
      OCR1B = duty;
      return;
    case 13:
      bitSet(TCCR0A, COM0A1);
      OCR0A = duty;
      return;
```

Answer (score 2):

Аппаратная генерация ШИМ возможна только на пинах, которые прописаны в даташите как пины для аппаратного ШИМ.

На остальные пины можно выдать ШИМ только программно, что имеет ряд ограничений.

Comment: Я использую атмегу 2560 где пины с 2 по 13 имеют ШИМ, используя этот код у меня завёлся пин 13, но мне надо сделать все, и к сожалению, в интернете нет информации по остальным таймерам, ну или мне она не помогла

Comment: Я пишу именно кастомное ядро и я меняю генерацию ШИМ на более оптимизированную для Arduino mega 2560 т.е. у меня нет доступа к analogWrite()

Comment: Даже чтение даташита не помогло?

Comment: Не сильно, в итоге завёл ШИМ на 13,12,11,10, а 9 не хочет